# ASP.NET 2.0 Security Membership Provider Pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-2.0

I am creating a website in ASP MVC. Can anyone give me some advice on using the built-in membership provider in the following way.

I want my users to create an Administrative account for themselves and then create accounts for the people in their organization, or the people that they want to give access to.

I guess in a Database it will look something like this:

Companies have Administrators. Administrators can give users access.

I am sure this pattern is used all over the place, I am just not sure how to implement it. Especially using the membership providers.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special in implementing this. It can be easily accomplished by built-in features of ASP.NET 2.0:

1. Configure Web site to use membership (via `web.config`)
2. Enable role management (via `web.config <roles enabled="true"> tag`)
3. Add administrator accounts to `Administrators` role.
4. Control access to the administrative pages by using `[Authorize(Roles="Administrators")]` attribute in the controller action.
5. Require authentication on other non-admin actions (`[Authorize]`)

Comment: This works but the difference is the concept of Being an Admin within your own Organization.

Comment: You can have arbitrary number of roles. To make them work dynamically, you can manually check role presence instead of relying on Authorize. `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole` might help in this case.

Comment: Thanks Mehrdad for your answer. Are you suggesting that when users sign up, I programatically put them in the administrators group and then only allow them to add users to their application through busnies logic in the controller?

Comment: Create one admin role per *application* and add admins to their specific roles. Then programatically allow only specific actions.

Comment: By the way, for simplicity, you can add all of them in a global Admin group and use it to authorize access to admin page.

Answer (score 0):

When I did this, I used the Membership Provider for authentication however, the organization concept I created externally from the Provider. You could use the Profile Provider.

As for roles I would still use the Roles within the ASP.Net Membership Model.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a role for those people and name it something like organizational-admin, though that's a bit long, you catch my drift :). And give those the power to create users with a regular user role. At least that's how i did it in one of my applications.

Ofcourse you'll keep the admin to yourself or to the person who is in charge of this particular site.

[Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/07/14/asp-net-mvc-preview-4-release-part-1.aspx) has a small example of how to implement the roles in an action filter.